# Can't Connect to a PPTP VPN Server from Ubuntu 18.04 Linux

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn, pptp, pptpd

I try to PPTP as VPN Client. I try to many ways to a given IP address, user name and password using. I try using GUI and terminal both way but not succeed.

After I try to debug and found some errors. I try to resolve those but not succeed.

> tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep NetworkManager

```
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980745.9327] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="c7412e35-28d4-4825-b7a5-9c7e8a6a1070" name="VPN 1" pid=5831 uid=1000 result="success"
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980745.9406] vpn-connection[0x5636de916480,c7412e35-28d4-4825-b7a5-9c7e8a6a1070,"VPN 1",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 28721
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980745.9500] vpn-connection[0x5636de916480,c7412e35-28d4-4825-b7a5-9c7e8a6a1070,"VPN 1",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980745.9600] vpn-connection[0x5636de916480,c7412e35-28d4-4825-b7a5-9c7e8a6a1070,"VPN 1",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980745.9629] vpn-connection[0x5636de916480,c7412e35-28d4-4825-b7a5-9c7e8a6a1070,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: Using interface ppp0
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Oct  6 16:09:05 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980745.9856] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Oct  6 16:09:06 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980746.0001] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Oct  6 16:09:06 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980746.0004] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Oct  6 16:09:37 neos NetworkManager[1101]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Oct  6 16:09:37 neos NetworkManager[1101]: Connection terminated.
Oct  6 16:09:37 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980777.0179] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Oct  6 16:09:37 neos NetworkManager[1101]: Terminating on signal 15
Oct  6 16:09:37 neos NetworkManager[1101]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 66.181.169.163 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-28721 (pid 28728) terminated with signal 15
Oct  6 16:09:37 neos NetworkManager[1101]: Modem hangup
Oct  6 16:09:37 neos NetworkManager[1101]: <info>  [1601980777.0262] vpn-connection[0x5636de916480,c7412e35-28d4-4825-b7a5-9c7e8a6a1070,"VPN 1",0]: VPN service disappeared
```

If someone know where the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by clearing up all firewall rules (see https://serverfault.com/questions/200635/best-way-to-clear-all-iptables-rules how to do that with iptables).

It seems that the firewall I was testing recently left some rules in place, which started to block the VPN communication.